# How to print matching pattern only

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I need to print [PR:XXXXX] only.

Ex: `[Test][PR:John][Finished][Reviewer:SE]` to `[PR:John]` only. (PR tag)

Note:Other strings rather than the [PR:XXXXX] may changed time to time
Ex:

```
[Test][PR:Cook][Completed]
[Test][Finished][PR:Russell][Reviewer:SE]
[Dump][Reviewer:SE][Complete][PR:Arnold]
```

Note: There are no multi line inputs and only one PR tag is included in all of inputs.

Untill I create following sed command but it did not work:

```
sed "s/\[PR:[^]]*\]//"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use bash for this:

```sh
s='[Test][PR:Cook][Completed]'
regex='\[PR:[^]]*]'
[[ "$s" =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
# => [PR:Cook]
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/Op5Xcl).

You may use `grep`:

```sh
grep -o '\[PR:[^]]*]'
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/TWYAm8).

Or, you can use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -n 's/.*\(\[PR:[^]]*]\).*/\1/p'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/PhA3H7).

Or, you can use `awk`

```sh
awk 'match($0,/\[PR:[^]]*]/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/mqtU5m).

Answer (score 2):

If you only have 1 such field max per line and want a blank line printed if no such field exists on the line then using GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[[]PR:[^]]+]' '{print $1}' file
[PR:Cook]
[PR:Russell]
[PR:Arnold]
```

If you can have 0 to N such fields per line, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
[Test][PR:Cook][Completed]
[Test][Finished][PR:Russell][Reviewer:SE]
[Test][Finished][Reviewer:SE]
[Test][Finished][PR:Jack][PR:Russell][Reviewer:SE]
[Dump][Reviewer:SE][Complete][PR:Arnold]
```

then here's some of the options depending on your requirements:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[[]PR:[^][]+]' '{print $1}' file
[PR:Cook]
[PR:Russell]

[PR:Jack]
[PR:Arnold]
```

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[[]PR:[^][]+]' 'NF{print $1}' file
[PR:Cook]
[PR:Russell]
[PR:Jack]
[PR:Arnold]
```

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[[]PR:[^][]+]' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' file
[PR:Cook]
[PR:Russell]
[PR:Jack]
[PR:Russell]
[PR:Arnold]
```

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[[]PR:[^][]+]' '{$1=$1} 1' file
[PR:Cook]
[PR:Russell]

[PR:Jack] [PR:Russell]
[PR:Arnold]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 1 occurrences of `[PR` to be printed in a single line then try following.

```
awk '{while(match($0,/\[PR:[^]]*\]/)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}' Input_file
```

Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` to find all blocks which have `[PR.....]` in them, then printing all occurrences until all are printed in each line.

Answer (score 2):

Use this perl command line:

```
perl -pe 's/\[[^P][^R][^:].*?\]//g' your_file
```

Test Below:

```
$ echo "[Test][Finished][PR:Russell][Reviewer:SE][PR:Rachel]"|perl -pe 's/\[[^P][^R][^:].*?\]//g'
[PR:Russell][PR:Rachel]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another perl:

```sh
perl -lne 'print join "", grep {/^\[PR:/} /\[.+?\]/g' file
```

This will accomodate multiple PR tags on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a a shorter `gnu-awk` solution (using same input file as in Ed's answer):

```sh
awk -v RS='\\[PR:[^]]+]' 'RT {print RT}' file

[PR:Cook]
[PR:Russell]
[PR:Jack]
[PR:Russell]
[PR:Arnold]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Ruby:

```
ruby -lne 'puts $_.scan(/\[PR.+?\]/).join("")' file
```

This accommodates multiple PR tags per line.